# Divisor Polynomials

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, q-analogs

For an integer $n>0$, we may define a polynomial $$p_n(x) = \sum_{d\mid n} x^d.$$Have such polynomials been seriously studied and do they have any interesting properties?

Looking at this more, I realize this might viewed as a $q$-analogue of the divisor counting function, but I am not too familiar with $q$-analogues and how they are used, so any information on this would be appreciated. As on outsider to this field, I assume that one often does not consider subtracting and multiplying $q$-analogues, and finding their magnitudes, so this may not be suitable for my purposes described. Regardless I am interested to hear any comments on this perspective if this is a studied $q$-analogue.

**Motivation:**

For distinct finite sets $A,B\subset \Bbb{N}$, there exists some minimal $k\le \min_{S\in\{A,B\}}\{\max_{x\in S}\{x\}\}$ such that $|\{n\in A:k\mid n\}|\neq |\{m\in B: k\mid m\}|$. We have that
$$ \prod_{n\in A} p_n(x)  -\prod_{n\in B} p_m(x) =\Theta(x^{k+L-1})$$near zero. (here $L = \min\{|A|,|B|\}$)

Right now this seems like a daunting way to calculate $k$ but I am wondering if these polynomials are well understood to perhaps inspire some way to use them in a proof.

Comment: As it stands, it seems to be just $x^{\sigma(n)}$. What's interesting about that?

Comment: $$\prod_{d\mid  n} x^d = x^{\sum_{d\mid n}d} = x^{\sigma(n)}$$

Comment: I'm guessing the OP meant $\sum_{d\mid n} x^d$.

Comment: @GregMartin yes I intended to use a sum. haha, only after I typed up some further motivation did I realize my initial typo.

Comment: The generating function  of those polynomials is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n(x) t^n=\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{(xt)^d}{1-t^d}$